# Angular UI Bootstrap Modal, bind model changes immediately

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use Angular UI Bootstrap Modal. And I want to have the changes to the model to be shown immediately.

This is the controller:

```
$scope.testInputField = "";
$scope.showModal= function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'partials/modal.html',
        controller: 'ModalController',
        resolve: {
            inputTest: function () {
                return $scope.testInputField;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function () {
        // Do stuff
    }, function () {
        console.log("Some Error");
    });
}
```

I have testInputField model also in my partial view.
And this is the the modal controller

```
controller('ModalController', [ '$scope', '$modalInstance', 'inputTest', function ($scope, $modalInstance, inputTest) {

        $scope.inputTest = angular.copy(inputTest);    

        $scope.keyPressed = function (key) {
            $scope.inputTest+= key;
            console.log($scope.inputTest);
        };

    } ])
```

So basically what I want whenever changes are made to with the keyPressed method, the modal in my main controller to be changed at the same time. Is there a possibility to accomplish this with UI bootstrap modals current code

Answer (score 0):

For this remove angular.copy method and try again. As it remove the data binding of the object.

Comment: I have tried it, and still not. The funny thing is that I have done this couple of months ago, and it was unintentionally (That's how I know that it's possible), but now I can't replicate the behaviour